# How to make phone calls using Xamairn forms?

Tags: xamarin.forms

I'm new in xamarin and I want make a phone call directly (without opening the dialler). I tried with this example but it doesn't work.
[Click](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/e4bad6/code-to-start-call-in-xamarin-forms) Please help

```
public class PhoneCall_Droid : IPhoneCall
{
    public void MakeQuickCall(string PhoneNumber)
    {
        try
        {
            var uri = Android.Net.Uri.Parse(string.Format("tel:{0}", PhoneNumber));
            var intent = new Intent(Intent.ActionCall, uri);
            Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Context.StartActivity(intent);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            new AlertDialog.Builder(Android.App.Application.Context).SetPositiveButton("OK", (sender, args) =>
            {
                //User pressed OK
            })
            .SetMessage(ex.ToString())
            .SetTitle("Android Exception")
            .Show();
        }
    }        
}
```

Comment: "doesn't work" tells us nothing useful.  Does it crash?  Throw an exception or error?  Have you used the debugger to verify that your code is actually being executed?

Comment: yeah i tested the code but takes the phone number but doesn't call it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there are two error in your code above:

1.`Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Context` could not get the correct context.

you could defined a static variable in MainActiviy like :

```
public static MainActivity Instance;
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
   {
      TabLayoutResource = Resource.Layout.Tabbar;
      ToolbarResource = Resource.Layout.Toolbar;

      base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
      global::Xamarin.Forms.Forms.Init(this, savedInstanceState);

      Instance = this;

      LoadApplication(new App());

    }
```

you also could use the **Current Activity Plugin**,you could refer to [Current Activity](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/CurrentActivityPlugin)

2.After Android6.0 you should requests the [runtime permissions](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/xamarin/requesting-runtime-permissions-in-android-marshmallow/) and the [official doucument](https://developer.android.com/training/permissions/requesting)

here is a simple example:

```
[assembly: Xamarin.Forms.Dependency(typeof(PhoneCall_Droid))]
namespace App18.Droid
{
  class PhoneCall_Droid: IPhoneCall
   {
     public void MakeQuickCall(string PhoneNumber)
      {
        try
        {
            if(ActivityCompat.CheckSelfPermission(MainActivity.Instance, Android.Manifest.Permission.CallPhone) != Android.Content.PM.Permission.Granted ){

               ActivityCompat.RequestPermissions(MainActivity.Instance, new string[] {Android.Manifest.Permission.CallPhone }, 1);
                return;
            }
            else
            {
            var uri = Android.Net.Uri.Parse(string.Format("tel:{0}", PhoneNumber));
            var intent = new Intent(Intent.ActionCall, uri);
            MainActivity.Instance.StartActivity(intent);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.Instance).SetPositiveButton("OK", (sender, args) =>
            {
                //User pressed OK
            })
            .SetMessage(ex.ToString())
            .SetTitle("Android Exception")
            .Show();
        }
    }     
  }
}
```

and you also could to use the nugetpackage **Plugin.Permissions** to request runtime permissions(Permission.Location)
refer to [Plugin.Permissions](https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/PermissionsPlugin)

finally you could call like

```
DependencyService.Get<IPhoneCall>().MakeQuickCall(phonenumber);
```